# Scrollpane destroy element on hide

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I have a bit complicated scenario with jscrollpane, and a problem with the scrolled element disappearing...

I call jscrollpane with this in js root

```
var $scrollfix = $('.sidebar nav').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
```

Then have in doc ready

```
$scrollfix;
```

And in window resize

```
$scrollfix.reinitialise();
```

And then I need to remove the jscrollpane when the menu (where the scroll is placed) is closed with a button, and then restore the function when it is opened

```
$(".close").on('click', function(e){
    // Close menu
    // jScrollpane
    $scrollfix.destroy();   
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(".open").on('click', function(e){
    // Open menu
    // jScrollpane
    $scrollfix; 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But, it doesn't work at the second open after close, I believe because the $scrollfix.destroy(); removes completely the jscrollpane. 
How can I get it back or not remove it completely, just disable it on the closed menu?

Comment: Why not just hide it and then show it again?

Comment: Hiding is not good, because it needs completely different size and setup...